# Building heap in O(N) in java instead of O(NlogN)

Tags: java, heap

To build heap, we use PriorityQueue class in java. Is there a way using inbuilt library/class to build heap directly from an array in O(N) instead of pushing each element individually to build heap in O(NlogN)?

Comment: @Razib, No,it's not a duplicate.  In java, we can't take entire array at a time  and build heap in O(n) (as per my knowledge) . We have to insert each element of the array individually into the heap and that takes O(NlogN). So my question is, is there a way to take the entire array and build heap in O(N) ? I am well aware of the fact that time complexity required to build heap from an array is O(N).

Comment: I voted to reopen since the marked dupe explains why it's computationally possible, and not how to do it with Java's built-in PriorityQueue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [the constructor that takes a collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)):

```
new PriorityQueue<String>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
```

True to form, the Java Docs don't mention anything about complexity, but reading [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#l273) shows that the OpenJDK uses the typical `O(n)` heapify approach rather than inserting in a loop:

```
private void initFromCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    initElementsFromCollection(c);
    heapify();
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to build heap of objects. I don't find a constructor where we can pass both collection and comparator as parameters. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: The only workaround I see is to wrap the objects in something that inherits Comparable and uses the comparator. At that point you might as well copy-paste a heapify algorithm instead of using PriorityQueue